# Monthly transacting users as proportion of those for rolling 12 month period, but with grouping - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, presto

I'm trying to work out how to write a query that gets users that were active over the previous 12 months, for a given month in 2017, and then transacted in a month.

Example:

For Dec 2017, who made a transaction, and what is this as a proportion of everyone that transacted over Dec 2016 - Dec 2017

The issue i'm having is that I also need to group these users by their product and country

Here is a row that I have:

customer ID | transaction_date | receiver country | product bought | transaction ID

I have tried a few methods like:

```
WITH transacting_dec_users AS (
SELECT
  user_id AS transactor,
  COUNT(*) AS transactions
  FROM database
      WHERE transaction_date >= '2017-12-01'
        GROUP BY user_id),

dec_actives AS (
SELECT
  user_id,
  transactions,
  COUNT(*) AS active_in_12_months,
  product,
  receive_country,
  sender_country

    FROM database t1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN transacting_users t2 ON t2.transactor = t1.user_id
      WHERE transaction_date >= '2016-12-01'
      GROUP BY 1,2,4,5,6)


SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN transactions IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actives_not_transact,
  SUM(CASE WHEN transactions IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS transactor
  FROM actives
```

I did try doing subqueries but I can't get them to work with my groupings, as I need to group each customer in countries and products

My ideal result would be:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would a firm commitment to one database or another (Postgres?  Presodb?)

Comment: Sure, I said both Postgres and PrestoDB since I can run the query on either

Comment: Just added a picture of my ideal result - does it make sense? So I can't just get those that transacted in Dec, then that as a proportion of those that transacted in a twelve month window, since I have to group the data by product and country

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your desired result: for each (month, service, receiver_country) calculate the number of users who transacted and also calculate the number of users who transacted within a year of that month. This query should do the trick (it's untested, so a couple of fixes may be in order).

```
; with
    TransactedThisMonth as (
        select    date_trunc('month', transaction_date) as month
                , service
                , receiver_country
                , count(distinct user_id) as transacting_users
            from table_name
            group by  date_trunc('month', transaction_date)
                    , service
                    , receiver_country
    )
select a.*, sum(b.transacting_users) as actives
    from TransactedThisMonth a
    left join TransactedThisMonth b
        on b.service = a.service
        and b.reciever_country = a.receiver_country
        and b.month between a.month - interval '1 year' and a.month
    group by  a.month
            , a.service
            , a.receiver_country
            , a.transacting_users
```